# Crystal Reports for VS 2010

Tags: c#, sql, database, crystal-reports-2010

I want to use Crystal Reports in my project. I want to join two or three tables and present them in my report.

For example: I have an `information` table, which contains the information of the people with an ID, and a `post` table which contains the wage value of every person that has an `id` column. I want to join these two tables and show them in one report page. My report should have this columns:

```
ID (the id of person)
name (from information table)
wage (wage of this person form post table)
```

How should I do this?
I found that i should use "view"  and I have maked a "view" in my database and add it to my dataset But I don't know what should I do in continue? any good suggudtion?